# My android emulator(android 2.2) on eclipse wont redeploy

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, adt

If I run the application for the first time it loads just fine. But if I make even the tiniest of changes and hit the run button again, the progress tab shows "launching testphase" (project name) and it gets stuck on 27 %.

Even if I end the process it just shows cancel requested. If I close the eclipse application on my computer and restart it and run the same application, then it works just fine but only once.

Comment: what tools and adt version are you running?

Comment: have you tried closing (only) the emulator window before redpeloying your apk?